# Java : string.replace(oldChar , newChar) ignoring another command

Tags: java, string, eclipse, replace

So I am a beginner in programming and I am working in Eclipse.
I am trying to get a word to lower case and then to delete the spaces if there are any so that i can later check if a word is palindrome or not. But when I enter word.replace it completely ignores the toLowerCase command and just deletes the spaces.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);    

System.out.print("Enter a word to transform: ");

String word = scan.nextLine();

String newWord = word.toLowerCase();

newWord = word.replace(" " , "");

System.out.println(newWord);
```

So with this code if I enter "An A" i get

```
AnA
```

But what i should get is :

```
ana
```

And for some reason this happens in eclipse whereas in NetBeans it works normally. Any suggestions ?

Comment: `newWord = newWord.replace(" " , "");`..

Comment: The code you've provided won't do what you want in NetBeans either, btw...

Comment: Who up-voted this question?

Comment: When I see the answer I realize how dumb I am xd Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `newWord = word.replace(" " , "");` with `newWord = newWord.replace(" " , "");`

Comment: When I see the answer I realize how dumb I am xd

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
newWord = word.replace(" " , "");
```

write

```
newWord = newWord.replace(" " , "");
```